# Why only structures corresponding to valleys on PES are taken into account?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have had to ask this question again because it was marked as a duplicate but it wasn't. Here it goes..

Suppose we want to estimate $G_f^\circ$ of a molecule. If it has rotational conformers, right way to calculate $G$ should include a Boltzmann average of them.
We will do it as:

$$\large \langle G_f^\circ \rangle = \frac{\sum_{i}G_f(i)e^{-G_f(i)/k_BT}}{\sum_{i}e^{^{-G_f(i)/k_BT}}}$$
where the sum goes over the conformers.

**Question:**

Why $\langle G_f^\circ \rangle$ is estimated as the sum of $G_f(i)$ of only most stable conformers? (corresponding to minima on PES)

**Example**

Suppose the following rotational conformers:

[image]

Consider the $y-axis$ to be gibbs free energy, we would estimate $\langle G_f^\circ \rangle$ as the sum of structures corresponding to minima (ie 60º, 180º), **but there are non-minimum structures around 180º with less energy than the minima in 60º**. Why aren't them considered?

**EDIT**

Someone could argue that a conformer in 150º won't exist because there will be a driving force to 180º, but if we take the relative energies $\frac{G_f(150º)}{G_f(60º)}$ we get that 150º must have almost the same population as 60º. There might be some criteria I am missing or maybe a conceptual error.

Any edit will be welcome.

Comment: It could be that the unstable conformers are so low a fraction of the species as to be negligible.

Comment: No, the last part of the post tries to explain that point.@a-cyclohexane-molecule

Comment: Are you only considering global minima, then? In your question statement, you mention local minima, and I'm not sure to which you refer in the last part of your post.

Comment: No, I mean, why estimate mean gibbs free energy as the sum of gibbs free energy of only most stable conformers?@a-cyclohexane-molecule. Thanks for the comments..

Comment: I think this is a good question because I would like to see a rigorous explanation of this. However, my intuition from the previous iteration of this question remains the same that the issue in how we define a state. I think the argument at the end of your post is invalid because it implicitly assumes that $150^{\circ}$ is an occupiable state of the system. The only way it would be at that configuration is a brief fluctuation of around the bottom of the $180^{\circ}$ well or en route to the $60^{\circ}$ well.

Comment: @Tyberius it is an occupiable state of the system, why not? It is a position of nucleus..

Comment: @HernanMiraola by analogy, think of a two state system: you are in an airplane flying at a constant height or you are on a level stretch on the ground. You can pass between the two states and briefly be at a point that doesn't coincide with those two states. But you will rapidly collapse to one or the other. If you jump out of the plane, there is zero probability that you hang in the air somewhere in between the ground and the plane. The same is true if you jump from the ground. The space in between the states is not occupiable in this sense.

Comment: When you are using the Gibbs energy, then the vibrational modes within the minimum are already considered, and the nuclei arrangement at angles slightly off the minimum correspond to vibrational distortions.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of thermodynamics we consider is at equilibrium, we is the issue here.

At equilibrium we will only find our S states at the bottom of the valleys (or minima) populated.  This this because they have now force acting on them to drive them to another configuration.

An important relationship to remember with potential energy surfaces is:
$$
F = -\frac{dE}{dx}
$$
Force is the negative derivative of potential energy with respect to some coordinate.
This means that the driving force is given by the slope of the PES and is pushing down the PES.
Then a molecule with a $\phi = 150^\circ$ experiences a rotational force pushing it towards the minimum at $\phi = 180^\circ$.

#### Answer:

The result is that any molecule not at a minimum will be quickly driven towards the nearest minimum, so only the minima will be occupied and need to be summed over.

#### Side Note - Maxima

Maxima (the peaks) also experience zero force.  However this is only true at the exact peak itself.  Any point infinitesimally far away from the maxima experiences a force pushing it down the hill into a minima.

Thermal fluctuations and collisions with other molecules will continually slightly nudge the molecules around on the potential energy surface.  At maxima this will push any molecules there off the peaks and down into minima.  In minima, the force will bring the molecules back into the minima.

Comment: Nice answer. And what about the relation $G_f(150)/G_f(60)$? Why is that reasoning wrong? I mean, we don't consider them because are only a few at equilibria?

Comment: That relationship is only valid for comparing the population of different minima, hence not for $G_f(150^\circ)$ as $150^\circ$ is not a minima.  The population of any state that is not a minima will be zero (or at most , briefly, vanishingly small before relaxing back to the minima).

Comment: I think there must be a deeper explanation, I mean, I am not sure that because it is not a minima we can't take that fraction of the previous comment. But it is helpful..thanks..

Comment: I'm not sure I believe this statement: "At equilibrium we will only find our S states at the bottom of the valleys (or minima) populated." At equilibrium these states should be populated according to the Boltzmann distribution, and certainly higher-energy states have some, if little, population.

Comment: @user213305 What about cis/trans isomers when a double is present? Should treat them as rotational conformers?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this is an approximation. It is, however, a much better approximation than you might think. The assumption is that each of the wells are shaped approximately the same. Furthermore, because the population of a state decreases exponentially with energy, it is really the approximation that each of the wells is shaped the same near the minimum.

It is well known that the smaller the displacements from the minimum, the more harmonic the motion will be. So, a measure of how much error is introduced by this approximation is the difference in harmonic frequency of the torsion in each of these wells. And, in the case that the frequencies in each of these wells is the same, the equation you have written is exact within the harmonic approximation. If the true (experimental) frequencies are identical, then the equation you have written is exact.

To be extra clear, for identically shaped wells, all deviations from the minimum energy structure will cancel out because when you do the Boltzmann averaging in each well, the population above any minimum will follow a Boltzmann distribution. Thus, the contributions from these deviations will be very minimal, and depend on there being different shapes of the well.

Probably the simplest way to include the shapes of the different wells in a calculation like this would be to construct the PES using some kind of *ab initio* method and then do a dynamics simulation on this surface to get the free energies this way.

Answer (score 0):

The Boltzmann distribution doesn't only take into account the most stable conformers. It can take the energy of any conformer (relative to the energy of the most stable conformer).

I assume that you're calculating the Gibbs energy using $\Delta G = - RT \text{ ln}K$. In this equation, $K$ represents the equilibrium constant between two local minima, i.e. between *anti* and *gauche*. So, when you calculate the Gibbs energy in this way, you're actually calculating the Gibbs energy for the rotation between two conformers (you can sort of imagine this as a reaction).

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I edit about G, I will add it again.

Comment: The standard Gibbs free energy is "the change of Gibbs free energy that accompanies the formation of 1 mole of a substance in its standard state from its constituent elements in their standard states". You only need to consider the elementary components and the minimum energy structure.